# How do I filter my api results to only show users that's either online or offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

me again.  I've managed to almost finish this project without help (quite chuffed), but alas I need some aid now.  I'm trying to design a tabbed menu that filter the results of my API calls to: Show all users, Show users only online and show users only offline.  Please help.

Please see my code attached below:

```
    <body class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid center" id="title">
    <h1 class="text-center">My Twitch.TV Favorites List</h1>
    <div class="text-center" id="mainLink"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">Filter: 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#userDisplay">All</a></li>
      <li id="menuOnline"><a href="#userDisplay">Online</a></li>
      <li id="menuOffline"><a href="#userDisplay">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid center" id="userDisplay">
    <div class="container col-md-1" id="logo"></div>
    <div class="container col-md-2" id="name"></div>
    <div class="container col-md-8" id="activity"></div>
    <div class="container col-md-1" id="status"></div>    
  </div>
</body>
```

...and my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userArr = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "freecodecamp",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas",
    "Blackbat023",
    "thewildfirecommunity"
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < userArr.length; i++) {
    var usersData ="https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/" +userArr[i] +"?callback=?";
    var channelsData ="https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/" +userArr[i] +"?callback=?";
    var streamsData ="https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" +userArr[i] +"?callback=?";


    $.getJSON(channelsData, function(users) {
      //console.log(users);
      $("#userDisplay").append(function(){
      $("#logo").append("<img src=" +users.logo +' class="img-resonsive img-thumbnail" alt="Logo" />');
      $("#name").append('<h4>' +users.name +"</h4> (" +users.updated_at +")<br><br>");
      $("#activity").append('Acitvity: <h4>'+users.status +"</h4><br>");
      });
    });

    $.getJSON(streamsData, function(streams) {
      //console.log(streams);
      var streamData = streams.stream;
      if (streamData === null) {
        $("#status").append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vz0GuT9.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Offline" />'
        );
      } else {
        $("#status").append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4jbBgtn.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Online" />'
        );
      }

      $(".active").onClick(function(){
        window.reload;
      });
      $("#menuOnline").onClick(function(){
        var statArr = $.grep(userArr, function(element, index){
          return(streamData != null);
        });
      });
      $("#menuOffline").onClick(function(){
        var statArr = $.grep(userArr, function(element, index){
          return(streamData == null);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?', function(fccData){
    //console.log(fccData);
    if(fccData.stream === null){
      $("#mainLink").append('<h2><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp" target="blank">We are currently offline</a></h2>');
    } else {
      $("#mainLink").append('<h2><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp" target="blank">Please join us on Twitch.TV</a></h2>');
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: Would be super useful to see a sample of your response from the AJAX call.

Comment: please help us by describing where the current code goes wrong. What can it do correctly, and at what point does it fail / behave incorrectly?

Comment: Since you said "Me Again", I checked your history.  It would be great if you would upvote / accept answers that solved your problems for other questions you've asked - that's the way SO is designed to work, and part of what encourages people to actually give you answers....

Comment: I don't understand your `$.grep` calls. They're not doing anything with `element` or `index`. You also shouldn't be binding the event handlers inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't think `.onClick` is a jQuery function. You need to write just `.click`.  Also you seem to repeatedly assign event handlers to the same elements (due to the loop), one for each item in the user array. So every time one of the links is clicked, 9 "click" event functions would fire. Is that your intention? lastly, why does the "active" one reload the page? Surely it should just unfilter the data?

Comment: @cale_b Sorry I'm still a bit of a noob on this forum... haven't figured out all the functions.  Barmar & ADyson Sorry, my mistake ... still learning :).  The idea was to apply the effects of those functions to every index within the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating the HTML for the users, give them a class that indicates whether they're online or offline.

```
  if (streamData === null) {
    $("#status").append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vz0GuT9.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail user-offline" alt="Offline" />'
    );
  } else {
    $("#status").append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4jbBgtn.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail user-online" alt="Online" />'
    );
  }
```

Then you can use these classes to hide or show the appropriate users:

```
$("#menuOnline").click(function() {
    $("#status .user-online").show();
    $("#status .user-offline").hide();
});
$("#menuOffline").click(function() {
    $("#status .user-offline").show();
    $("#status .user-online").hide();
});
```

These click handlers should be at the top level of your `$(document).ready()` function, not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: By all the Tech Gods that's BRILLIANT!!  I totally didn't think of using .show() and .hide(). =)  I was going for something like trying to filter the username array.  Thanks so much @Barmar!  The other problem now though is that it would only show and hide the status images and not the entire  user output because of me using bootstrap grids, but I've got a method to go with now.  Thanks again

Comment: Just add the appropriate classes to whatever elements you're using to hold the information.

Comment: Ok I added .removeClass() and .addClass() functions to the other elements within the for loop as I want certain classes to only react to the .show() and .hide() functions depending on the user's "status".  But it's doing some funky stuff now.  check it out: [link](https://codepen.io/BlackBat023/pen/yXodvE)

Comment: Don't put `.` in the class in `addClass` and `removeClass`. That's selector syntax.

Comment: You still have `$("#menuAll").click()` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: The list of users isn't inside `<div id="status">`, so `$("#status .user-online")` won't match them. Did I misunderstand that part of the code in the question?

Comment: Well the code is suppose to eliminate all users from the #userDisplay output if they're offline if you click on the online menu tab and eliminate all the online users when the offline tab is clicked.  When you click on all it's suppose to display online and offline users again.

Comment: I was looking at the second `$.getJSON`, which appends to `#status`. Anyway, the idea is the same. Whichever DIV you're appending the users to, you should use that in the `#menuOnline` and `#menuOffline` code.

Comment: what if I do the streams $.getJSON call inside the channel $.getJSON call and do all the .appending in the 2nd call?  Would that work?  Also I'm thinking of getting rid of the several col-md's and just have one cal-md-12 for the iterated results.

Comment: I don't know what the APIs do, so I can't really answer that. But my answer is really unrelated to the API calls. As long as you put the proper classes on the data and select them from the DIVs you want, it should work. It's just a general-purpose filter.

Comment: OK I've now gotten it to this point [link](https://codepen.io/BlackBat023/pen/yXodvE?editors=0110) and the filtering works.  I'm having difficulty with the styling though.  When you click on the Offline tab it displays the result, but it's like it completely ignores the css.  The Online and All tab results works fine though.

Comment: You have some invalid CSS: `align-text` should be `text-align`, and there's no such thing as `float: center`. I'm not sure if these are the problem, though. You should use the DOM inspector to see how the CSS is being applied to the elements. And invalid CSS is highlighted in the Styles sidebar.

Comment: OK finally I believe I might have fixed the problem.  You were right about the CSS issues, but the majour problem was a </div> element closing in the wrong spot making the #status element a child of the #activity element.  Just goes to show how something so simple can screw up the output completely.  Welcome to coding right? =D Anyway you were a major help man, big ups to you and thank you so much for everything.